# How to plot a time serie having only business day without jump between the missing days

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a timeserie that contains measures where each record is 10 minutes time frame and only from monday to friday. My issue is that when I plot this with matplotlib it creates a (legitimate) jump between friday and monday but i would like to display values of end of friday next to start of monday. Is there a way to represents this type of line plot?

Comment: could you please provide a sample dataset and what have you tried ?

Comment: You might try to change your timestamp from `datetime` to `str`. But ticks are going to look awful.